# Why do I get "including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Everytime I run a spec, even if the spec passes, e.g.

```
$ rspec spec/integration/view_homepage_spec.rb 
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
.

Finished in 0.6174 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

Randomized with seed 14130

$
```

My Gemfile has:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

My spec_helper has:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara'
include Capybara::DSL
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f } 
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
end
```

If I comment out the `include Capybara::DSL` then my capybara methods like `visit` don't work.

Comment: It's right there: `include Capybara::DSL` in the top-level scope. Doing so is not recommended. Include it in your Capybara-specific tests.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because including `Capybara::DSL` in the global scope is not recommended.

This includes many methods globally in the system, which could interfere with your own code.

Here's the correct way:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL, :type => :feature
end
```

Comment: `:type => :feature` should work for specs under spec/acceptance, spec/features, and spec/integration. You don't want to be using Capybara::DSL for controller, model, view specs.

Comment: I had to remove `:type => :feature` in order to get it working.

Comment: Please note that the `type` option no longer (since RSpec 3) 'magically' applies the configuration option to tests in `spec/features` - see http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#filetype_inference_disabled_by_default