# How can I avoid "including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!" with Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

After switching my Cucumber tests from Selenium-Webdriver to Capybara, everything works as expected. But I keep getting this warning:

```
"including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!"
```

Googling for this error message turned up a bunch of results, but all of them are for RSpec; essentially, they recommend to move the `include Capybara::DSL` to the RSpec configuration (see e.g. [Why do I get "including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616683/why-do-i-get-including-capybaradsl-in-the-global-scope-is-not-recommended)). I've tried to do the same with my Cucumber config, but to no avail (see Approaches section below).

**My current code**

features/youtube.feature:

```
Feature: Searching for videos 

  Scenario: Searching for videos 
  Given I go to the YouTube web site
    And I search for "text adventure" 
   Then I should see the text "GET LAMP: The Text Adventure Documentary"
```

features/steps/youtube_steps.rb:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'rspec'

include RSpec::Expectations
include Capybara::DSL

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.run_server = false

When(/^I search for "(.*?)"$/) do |value|
  page.fill_in("search_query", :with => value)
  page.click_button("search-btn")
end

Then(/^I should see the text "(.*?)"$/) do |value|
  page.should have_content(value)
end

Given(/^I go to the YouTube web site$/) do
  Capybara.app_host = "http://www.youtube.com" 
  page.visit("")
end
```

**Approaches I've tried**

- putting `include Capybara::DSL` inside the `Before` hook (Result: Cucumber doesn't find the Capybara-specific methods like `page` anymore)
- putting `config.extend Capybara::DSL` inside the `BeforeConfiguration` hook (Result: Cucumber doesn't find the Capybara-specific methods like `page` anymore)
- using `include Capybara` instead of `include Capybara::DSL` (result: another warning, telling me this is outdated, and I should use `include Capybara::DSL` instead)

Where should I put my `include Capybara::DSL` to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Have you tried [This](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber). It suggests requiring `capybara/cucumber` which will include the DSL for you.

Comment: Doh! I even was on that page, but that must have escaped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to include the Capybara::DSL in the Cucumber steps rather than global scope. Cucumber allows you to do this using the [`World`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World).

The Capybara::DSL is included in the world by using the line:

```
World(Capybara::DSL)
```

As mentioned by @engineersmnky, you might want to just:

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
```

This would add the Capybara::DSL to the world, as well as the RSpec::Expectations. It also sets up a couple of hooks. You can see exactly what this would do by checking the [capybara/cucumber.rb file](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using `require 'capybara/cucumber' now, but it's certainly useful to know about `World`.